# Is it a good idea to run docker images on a robot?

Tags: docker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently thinking about running the ROS nodes required for a robot to work in separate docker containers. It can then be controlled remotely which nodes are supposed to run and where. I am also thinking about a central instance that manages configurations for nodes and robots to be matched.

I think this can make the whole setup more flexible an robust.

But it also adds some overhead and another abstraction layer.

Has anyone ever done this? Thoughts about this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248771/is-it-a-good-idea-to-run-docker-images-on-a-robot?/) by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) on ROS Answers with karma: 862 on 2016-11-24

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, we are doing this on our Pioneer 3-AT robots and it works fine. The main reason we did it was to replicate the setup across same robots (we have three Pioneers with slightly different hardware). With docker it is also easy to bring up the system automatically with something like:

```
docker run -d --restart=always pioneer3
```

If you are planning to use `roslaunch`, one thing to keep in mind is that the containers will be starting in parallel, meaning you have to make them wait for the container with `roscore` to start, otherwise `roslaunch` will start its own `roscore` in each container (though the `ROS_MASTER_URI` will clash I guess). This can be solved with the `--wait` flag for `roslaunch`.

What seems inconvenient to me is the development and debugging, so as you mentioned it might be necessary to write a 'supervisor' app to see the state of containers remotely etc.

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2016-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) on 2016-11-29**:
Thanks for the answer. Sounds interesting. Are you also using docker remote api to remotely start and stop containers?

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2016-12-02**:
Yes, I think so. Unfortunately I don't have any details right now about that.